# Matching genes in string in Python

Tags: python, regex, subset

I'm trying to match text strings (gene names) in a column from one file to text strings in a column of another, in order to create a subset the second.

For simplicity, the first will look more or less like this:

`hits = ["IL1", "NRC31", "AR", etc.]`

However, the column of interest in the second df looks like this:

`68           NFKBIL1;NFKBIL1;ATP6V1G2;NFKBIL1;NFKBIL1;NFKBI
236                                                  BARHL2
272                                             ARPC2;ARPC2
324                                                  MARCH5
...
11302        NFKBIL1;NFKBIL1;ATP6V1G2;NFKBIL1;NFKBIL1;NFKBI
426033                                        ABC1;IL1;XYZ2
...
425700                                                IL17D
426295                                              RAB3IL1
426474                                        IL15RA;IL15RA`

I came up with:

`df2[df2.UCSC_RefGene_Name.str.contains('|'.join(hits), na=False)]`

But I need to match the gene `IL1` if it falls in the middle of the string (e.g.row 426033 above) but not similar genes (e.g. row 426295 above).

How do I use regular expressions to say:
"*Match the any of the strings in `hits` when they have ';' or 'a blankspace' at either the beginning or the end of the gene name, but not when they have other letters or numbers on either side (which indicate a different gene with a similar name)*?

I also need to exclude any rows with NA in dataframe 2.

Yes, I know there are regex syntax documents, but there are too many moving parts here for me to make sense of them.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to use a dynamic field inside your regex.

This would work, as you can see in [this](https://regex101.com/r/tfocE5/3) example:

```
gene = "IL1"
pattern = r'(?<!^)(?<=\s|;){0}(?![\w])'.format(gene)
```

Alternatively, you can capture the whole list of genes in the file: ([test](https://regex101.com/r/QHs8Qa/1/))

```
(?<!^)(?<=\s|;)[A-Z0-9]+
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This `(?<!^)(?<=\s|;)IL1(?![\w])` works for IL1, but I need to make it work for a list of multiple genes somehow. Any idea?

Comment: @CPR that’s what I wasn’t sure about in your question. I thought you were iterating over a list of genes, and then you can dynamically call the regex I’ve added. Alternatively you can read ALL the genes with the second regex and compare to your list

Comment: @CPR If you’ll write your final goal I might be help to help more

Comment: Thanks @GalAbra. My final goal is to have a subset of rows from the second dataset (which has 500 columns) whenever the *exact* match occurs in the reference column. Looking at the links you provided, the first example you provided **does work** for IL1, but I need it to work for a list of genes (e.g. I need to match IL1 or AR or NRC31 or DRD2 or DRD3 or etc.). Note: I don't care if the gene occurs only once among others (row 426033 in my example), or many times over - one perfect occurrence is sufficient to say "include in subset function". I hope that helps, and thank you again.

Comment: @CPR So as I mentioned, you can use the second regex to extract all the genes and cross the lists

Comment: I massively appreciate your help, but somehow we are getting our wires crossed. Number 2 example **does not** do what I need. Perhaps using your example is easier: Can I do `pattern = r'(?<!^)(?<=\s|;){0}(?![\w])'.format(gene)` but instead of `gene = "IL1"`, `gene = ["IL1", "ABC1", "XYZ2", ...]`. Note that I do **not** want every gene (I don't want  NFKBIL1, for example), only those I list in `gene`. Hopefully that helps. If not, thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

For character handling at such micro level the query will end up being clunky with high response time — if you're lucky to write a working one.

This's more of a script kind of operation.